# Update Results From MongoDB Before emmiting

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

Say I have this query

```
var query1 = usersrec.find({username:target}, {});
query1.exec(function (err, docs){
    if(err) throw ;
});
```

and it gives this result

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5806ba413202e30d68152aa4"), 
    "username" : "sammy", 
    "firstname" : "samuel", 
    "lastname" : "jackson", 
    "gender" : "male", 
    "phone" : "0123456789", 
    "image" : "sam.jpg"
}
```

I want to add a value which I get from another collection `{"Balance" : "1011"}` to this resulting document before emitting with socket.io.

I've tried many things and got errors, but this went through without adding the balance key/value:

```
docs[0].balance = '1011';
console.log(docs);
socket.emit('usernames', docs);
```

The document still retains its initial values. What am I missing?

Comment: Seems like you are using Mongoose, if so then you need to call the [**`lean()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) method on your query `query1.lean().exec(...)`. This will ensure that documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain javascript objects which you can manipulate and add the other balance property.

Comment: @chridam Thanks alot! Worked like a charm. Funny how tiny things you don't know can make a whole difference in code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using Mongoose and [Mongoose documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js) don't allow adding properties. You need to either call the [**`lean()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) method before **`exec()`** since documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain javascript objects:

From the docs:

```
var query1 = usersrec.find({username:target}, {});
query1.lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
    docs[0] instanceof mongoose.Document // false
});
```

So your code should look like:

```
var query1 = usersrec.find({username:target}, {});
query1.lean().exec(function (err, docs){
    if(err) throw ;
    docs[0].balance = '1011';
    console.log(docs);
    socket.emit('usernames', docs);
});
```

or cast the returned document to a plain object:

```
var query1 = usersrec.find({username:target}, {});
query1.exec(function (err, docs){
    if(err) throw ;
    docs = docs.map(function(o){ return o.toObject(); });
    docs[0].balance = '1011';
    console.log(docs);
    socket.emit('usernames', docs);
});
```

Comment: @chrisdam I applied this to a code, and stumbled on another glitch
please check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131084/mongodb-nested-query-returns-only-last-occuring-result